# Failed to get child node from json

Tags: c#, json

I have a json:

```
{"code":200,"status":"success","actRows":1,"data":[" {\"cmd\":\"gw\",\"seqno\":0000,\"EUI\":\"000000\",\"ts\":00000,\"fcnt\":0000,\"port\":00,\"freq\":0000,\"toa\":000,\"dr\":\"00004/5\",\"ack\":false,\"gws\":[{\"rssi\":-0000,\"snr\":-000,\"ts\":00000,\"tmms\":0000000,\"time\":\"2020-06-10T09:51:29.870751000Z\",\"gweui\":\"000000000\",\"ant\":0,\"lat\":00.00000000,\"lon\":00.000000}],\"bat\":254,\"data\":\"123456789\"}"]}
```

From this json i need to access last data from data. So I need value "123456789" (values are random generated by me, so there is actual data and no 0 and 123456789)

I am trying to access this node using:

```
string data = JObject.Parse(finalData)["data"][0]["data"].ToString();
```

What seems to be like a valid code to access this node, but it returns error:

```
Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue.
```

It bothers me because I can access any master node like a "code", "status", "actRows" and complete list of "data" but I am unable to access any child node of "data".

Do I have problem with escaping or with overall format of json? When I used json validator it seems like a valid json.

Comment: your json is not valid

Comment: _it seems like a valid json._ Nope, json list says that it's invalid, at least you are missing one curly bracket at the end

Comment: Seems like I copied it badly. Question edited.

Comment: The value of `data` is a string, notice the escaped quotes. So parse it as json then access what you need.

Comment: @Crowcoder Thats what I am doing, don't I

Comment: No, that's not what you are doing. By `data`, I meant the array named "data" in the json, not one of the other two things named "data". After your code runs, `string data` (you really need to change this name for clarity) is a string that itself must be parsed with `JObect.Parse`. However, you will encounter problems parsing the decimal values like 00.000000.

Comment: @Crowcoder idk, I didn't figured it out. I guess that I will just try to trim the string to get data somehow..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you need to do. **However, note that the lat and lon values of 00.000000 cannot be parsed so you have to deal with that somehow**. To run this code change lat and lon to values that can be parsed, like 10.000000 for instance.

```
//Parse the json as usual
JObject fullObject = JObject.Parse(json);

//Get a reference to the array in item "data"
JArray dataItem = (JArray)fullObject["data"];

//The content of the array is a STRING! Notice the escaped quotes.
//You have to do ANOTHER PARSE on the array item
JObject innerData = JObject.Parse(dataItem[0].Value<string>());

//Now you have json again and you can access "data"
string finalvalue = innerData["data"].Value<string>();
```

As far as dealing with the lat and lon values, you could do a string replace on the original string if you don't care about the values.

Comment: I see what you mean in that comment now. Thank you for help.